# What is the correct way to save my Oracle 19 container so I can launch it later with my Dockerfile?

Tags: oracle, docker

I created a running Oracle 19.3 container following the steps in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bastian.ohm/how-to-run-oracle-db-in-docker-6990780d4cac).

My question is, what is the "correct" way to save the running Oracle 19 image as a starting point for new containers?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want to achieve a little bit, I am trying to understand in order to help you. maybe what you can do is to do all stuff and use `docker save` to export an image and then you can reuse it, maybe upload it to a registry, is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @HernanGarcia Thanks for the help.  I want to have a clean Oracle data I can spin up for testing, and I want it to run create_db.sql on startup (which will change over time).  I have Oracle19 container running, should I use `docker save` to save it as `ava-db` and then use `FROM ava-db` in my Dockerfile?

Comment: yes, but docker save will create a tar file so this should be imported in your local registry and then run different container instances from it. Let me know if this worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the correct approach is to user docker 'commit'

docker commit <CONTAINER_ID> <NEW_IMAGE_NAME>